# pics being removed from the flowlayoutpanel

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, flowlayoutpanel

hello guys im making this application in VB that loads picture boxes from a file into a flowlayoutpanel and adds a click handler to each pic in order to display them in a bigger size. however when they are clicked are removed from the layoutpanel and i dont want that and dont understand why is happening. this is my code:

Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

```
Private folderPath As String
Private pics() As PictureBox

Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    FolderBrowser.SelectedPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory
    If FolderBrowser.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Return
    End If
    folderPath = FolderBrowser.SelectedPath()

    Dim fileNames As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath)
    If fileNames.Length = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to find any image files")
        Return
    End If
    Me.Text = folderPath
    ReDim pics(fileNames.Length - 1)

    For i As Integer = 0 To fileNames.Length - 1
        pics(i) = New PictureBox()
        With pics(i)
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(300, 200)
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            .Image = New Bitmap(fileNames(i))
            FlowPanel.Controls.Add(pics(i))
            AddHandler pics(i).Click, AddressOf pics_Click
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub pics_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim pic As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    With pic
        .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(500, 500)
        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        RemoveHandler pic.Click, AddressOf pics_Click
    End With
    Dim frm As New Form2
    FlowPanel.Controls.Add(pic)
    frm.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pic)
    frm.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frm.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pic)
```

A control can have only one parent.  So moving it to the new form will *remove* it from FlowPanel.  If you want a copy then you'll have to create a new PictureBox:

```
Dim pic As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
Dim newpic As PictureBox = new PictureBox()
With newpic
    .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(500, 500)
    .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    .Image = pic.Image
End With
Dim frm As New Form2
frm.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newpic)
frm.ShowDialog()
```